# addthis share vs custom share button

Tags: share, addthis

i need to add to my website a share-feature.

this php page should allow users to share my webiste on the social network, but i need to set a custom url, title, description and image.

i have try with addthis share buttons, but i m not sure that is possibile to fully customize the buttons... right?

there are other services like that? or in my case is better to add share button with facebook api, twitter api,..?

this is the addthis share code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xx"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom title, url and description by specifying addthis:title, addthis:url and addthis:description tags in you toolbox HTML like this:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"
    addthis:url="http://example.com"
    addthis:title="An Example Title"
    addthis:description="An Example Description">
```

However, Facebook and some other services don't respect the values sent to them and scrape your page for og:title, og:url and og:description tags.  So to be safe, specify the above in your AddThis code and also specify the same values for your og tags.  You can read more about the og tags here:

http://www.addthis.com/blog/2012/09/27/debugging-sharing-to-facebook

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: You could try this: http://sharebuttongenerator.aakilfernandes.com/